# How to automatecally set height of element(like div) depend on elements inside of it; css; html

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website on GitHub page.
And I'm trying to set the same header and footer to all pages I have.
I put all contents except header and footer to the main div.
On CSS, I have to set the height of main div.
But, it's better if the height of the div determined by elements inside of it.
Is there any way to do it?

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta chrset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/styles.css">
  <title>JCBMS SLED Team / Home</title>
  <style>
.main{
  height: 2500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}


  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "header">
      <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/QmrgYks/Copy-of-LOGO-Title-Horizontal.png" alt="SLED" class="header-logo" /></a>
    <div class = "header-link">
      <ul>
        <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/about.html"><li>About</li></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/projects.html"><li class="droplist">Project</li></a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
           <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/chromebook.html">Chromebook Helpdesk</a>
           <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/hoc.html">Hour of Code</a>
           <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/keepthecolor.html">#Keep the Color</a>
           <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/studentstour.html">New Students Tour</a>
           <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/subhelp.html">Sub Help</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/members.html"><li>Members</li></a>
        <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/blog.html"><li>Blog</li></a>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>SLED Team</h1>
      <h3>At J.C. Booth Middle School 2019-2020</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="downArrow bounce">
      <a href="#scroll"><img width="100" height="100" alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/4429Mnd/output-onlinepngtools.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="mission">
    <div id="scroll"></div>
    <h1>Our MIssion</h1>
      <h3>Improving the Warrior community experience with Ingenuiry, Creativity, Innovation</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="projects">
      <h1>Our Projects</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Chromebook Helpdesk  </li>
        <li>Hour of Code</li>
        <li>#Keep the Color</li>
        <li>New Students Tour</li>
        <li>Sub Help</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback">
      <h1>Help us Improve our Contents</h1>
      <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/feedback.html"><h3>Click here to send Feedback</h3></a>
    </div>
    <div class="follow">
      <h1>Follow us on</h1>
      <div class="social-icon">
        <a href="https://instagram.com/jcbmssledteam/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/DVfJwK5/iconfinder-1-Instagram-colored-svg-1-5296765.png" alt="insta" class="instagram"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jcbooth.sled"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/zJ0NCRG/iconfinder-Colored-Facebook3-svg-5365678.png" alt="faceook" class="facebook" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="footer">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/p4LvvdH/Copy-of-LOGO-White.png" alt="SLED Logo" class="footer-logo" />
      <div class="footer-list">
       <ul>
        <a href="#top"><li>Back to Top</li></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/jcbmssledteam/"><li>Instagram</li></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jcbooth.sled"><li>Facebook</li></a>
        <a href="mailto: jcbms-sled-team@mail.fcboe.org"><li>Jcbms-sled-team@mail.fcboe.org</li></a>
        <a href="https://www.fcboe.org/jcbms"><li>J.C. Booth Middle School</li></a>
        <a href="https://www.fcboe.org"><li>Fayette County Public Schools</li></a>
       </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the `height: 2500px;` property from your `main` class style. It will automatically resize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use height: auto
That will fit the content into the main div.

"If height: auto; the element will automatically adjust its height to allow its content to be displayed correctly" - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta chrset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/styles.css">
  <title>JCBMS SLED Team / Home</title>
  <style>
.main{
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}


  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "header">
      <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/QmrgYks/Copy-of-LOGO-Title-Horizontal.png" alt="SLED" class="header-logo" /></a>
    <div class = "header-link">
      <ul>
        <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/about.html"><li>About</li></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/projects.html"><li class="droplist">Project</li></a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
           <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/chromebook.html">Chromebook Helpdesk</a>
           <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/hoc.html">Hour of Code</a>
           <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/keepthecolor.html">#Keep the Color</a>
           <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/studentstour.html">New Students Tour</a>
           <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/subhelp.html">Sub Help</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/members.html"><li>Members</li></a>
        <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/blog.html"><li>Blog</li></a>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>SLED Team</h1>
      <h3>At J.C. Booth Middle School 2019-2020</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="downArrow bounce">
      <a href="#scroll"><img width="100" height="100" alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/4429Mnd/output-onlinepngtools.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="mission">
    <div id="scroll"></div>
    <h1>Our MIssion</h1>
      <h3>Improving the Warrior community experience with Ingenuiry, Creativity, Innovation</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="projects">
      <h1>Our Projects</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Chromebook Helpdesk  </li>
        <li>Hour of Code</li>
        <li>#Keep the Color</li>
        <li>New Students Tour</li>
        <li>Sub Help</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback">
      <h1>Help us Improve our Contents</h1>
      <a href="https://sledteam.github.io/sled/feedback.html"><h3>Click here to send Feedback</h3></a>
    </div>
    <div class="follow">
      <h1>Follow us on</h1>
      <div class="social-icon">
        <a href="https://instagram.com/jcbmssledteam/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/DVfJwK5/iconfinder-1-Instagram-colored-svg-1-5296765.png" alt="insta" class="instagram"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jcbooth.sled"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/zJ0NCRG/iconfinder-Colored-Facebook3-svg-5365678.png" alt="faceook" class="facebook" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="footer">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/p4LvvdH/Copy-of-LOGO-White.png" alt="SLED Logo" class="footer-logo" />
      <div class="footer-list">
       <ul>
        <a href="#top"><li>Back to Top</li></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/jcbmssledteam/"><li>Instagram</li></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jcbooth.sled"><li>Facebook</li></a>
        <a href="mailto: jcbms-sled-team@mail.fcboe.org"><li>Jcbms-sled-team@mail.fcboe.org</li></a>
        <a href="https://www.fcboe.org/jcbms"><li>J.C. Booth Middle School</li></a>
        <a href="https://www.fcboe.org"><li>Fayette County Public Schools</li></a>
       </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```